Nextjs problemas de renderizado de backgraound img
Estoy haciendo una página en la que se renderiza una imagen a través de la clase de tailwind bg-[url("path")]
El problema viene cuando lo estoy haciendo a través de una constante que uso como configuración:
import { MyCareer } from "@/interfaces/my-career/career.interface";
import { FaNodeJs } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { IoLogoAngular, IoSchool } from "react-icons/io5";
import { SiCsharp } from "react-icons/si";
import { GiArtificialIntelligence } from "react-icons/gi";

export const myCareerConfig: MyCareer[] = [
    {
        dateRange: 'blablabla',
        dotIcon: GiArtificialIntelligence,
        empress: 'blablabla',
        empressImage: 'bg-[url("path")]',
        description: `blablabla`
    } ... etc
]

Dicha constante la mapeo en el componente a visualizar:
//... paja
<div className={`${value.empressImage} bg-center bg-cover bg-no-repeat h-60 w-full`}></div>
//... paja

Hasta aquí no debería haber problema, ya que se superpone y debería obtener la imagen. El caso es que no se renderiza. Crea el hueco específico de la imagen con la url según el explorador del F12 pero no está renderizada.
¿Por qué puede ser?
Para darle un giro más, si dicha imagen la hardcodeo en el código, sin hacer un map, sino poniendo todos los componentes sin iterar nada, funciona perfectamente, Y CUANDO LO VUELVO A MAPEAR, funciona igual. Asumiría que es por cosa de la caché, pero refresco la página con el borrado de caché activado y funciona igual.

La imagen es local o la trae desde alguna API?

La imagen es una url de interet. Cualquiera de imágenes

Ya configuraste los domains de las imagenes en el archivo next.config.js?
